# Is it possible to search through http://irclogs.ubuntu.com?

Tags: irc

Is there a web front-end for http://irclogs.ubuntu.com that allows me to search through all the IRC chat logs?

I tried to google for `site:irclogs.ubuntu.com +search-term` but that doesn't seem to work reliably.

I'm **not** looking for a solution that fetches any of those files. :-)

Comment: This question might be better on [the Webapps StackExchange site](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

IRSeek.com might help you find what you are looking for it logs the ubuntu IRC channels

Comment: IRSeeK seems to be down for good.